# Database rule allowing to list children with read access

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a list of messages in my app, and I would like my users to retrieve a list of their own messages.

If I'm logged in as "user1" i can fetch **/messages/message1** without any problems, but if I want to retrieve all my messages (without being able to get access to other user's messages) with **/messages/** i get permission denied even though i have access to some of the child elements

How can I give my users a list of all of their child elements with read permission without knowing the IDs of the messages?

Thank you in advance.

Below is my database:

```
{
  "messages" : {
    "message1" : {
      "sender" : "user1_uid"
      },
    "message2" : {
      "sender" : "user1_uid"
    }
}
```

And here is my rule:

```
{
    "messages": {
        "$weddingId": {
            ".read": "data.child('sender').val() == auth.uid"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adolfo has one valid approach. He spreads the message data under user-specific nodes. This is very common in NoSQL databases, essentially building many "mini-tables of messages" instead of one large one.

Alternatively, you can keep the master list of messages where it is now, but create a so-called index of messages for each user:

```
{
  "messages" : {
    "message1" : {
      "sender" : "user1_uid"
      },
    "message2" : {
      "sender" : "user1_uid"
    }
  },
  "user_messages": {
    "user1_uid": {
      "message1": true,
      "message2": true
    }
  }
```

You'd keep the security rules for `messages` as you have them now, but add these for the new `user_messages` index:

```
"user_messages": {
  "$userId":{
    ".read": "$userId == auth.uid"
  }
}
```

With these in place, you'd load the message for a user by first loading the message IDs from `/user_messages/<authData.uid>` and then loading each individual message from `/messages/<messageId>`.

See also our [guide on creating data that scales](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#fanout) for more on this technique (called fan-out).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a refactoring to achieve what you are expecting since you wont be able to use `.orderByChild('sender').equalTo(user_uid)` because you are not giving read access to the `/messages`  branch (only for it childs).

You could work to have the `userId` as a branch in `/messages` and have all the player messages ids inside it. You will need to save your messages data like bellow:

```
{
  "messages" : {
    "userId" : {
        "message1" : {
            "text": "tetet"
        },
        "message2" : {
            "text" : "tetet2"
        }
    },
    "userId2": {...}
}
```

Then your rules will look like:

```
{
    "messages": {
        "$userId":{
            ".read": "$userId == auth.uid",
            "$weddingId": {
                //...
            }
    }
}
```

Finally, you will be able to have all the user messages with:

```
firebaseRef.child('messages').child(user_uid).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.val()){
        console.log(snapshot.val());
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have mentioned that "sender" cen be multiple user-ids and more senders can be added later - can you think of a way of facilitating this?

Comment: @larsd You would need to simply add the messageId to all the proper users as well.