# Firebase database: Unable to write database rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

for past couple days I'm trying to write a firebase real-time database rule but no luck.
Here is what I want to do, I have a orders reference in my database and I want allow read to users on only orders which they have placed, the orders reference contains orders from all the users. To verify that which customer has placed order, the order object has a customerId child.
Here is my code.

```
...
"orders": {
  ".read": "auth.token.admin === true",
    "$orderId": {
      ".read": "auth.uid === root.child('orders').child($orderId).child('customerId').val()"
    }
}
...
```

Am adding listener to orders reference and  using equalTo method passing customerId to query orders for a specific customer. I always get permission denied error.

I don't know how to fix this, any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpfull if you include your database structure and the code you are using for reading.

Comment: This is the code I used to query orders: val ordersRef = database.getReference("orders")

ordersRef.orderByChild("customerId"). equalTo(/* user uid */).addChildEventListener(/* listener */). For structure of order, it has details of items, time, customerId etc nothing special there.

Comment: Can nobody help me?

Comment: I have found solution to the problem, check this out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329815/database-rule-allowing-to-list-children-with-read-access "here")